# XSLT apply templates issue

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

If we say apply templates for a particular node , it ll apply in the entire xml wherever it finds that node/tag.

My issue is i ve a xml , where i need to apply templates based on condition , basically maintain some order.

Input xml :

```
enter code here
<step>
 <note>..</note>
 <para>..</para>
 <table>
  ..
  ..
 </table>
 <note>...</note>
 <table>
 ..
 ..
 </table>
 <table>
 ..
 ..
</table>
<note>...</note>
<text>...</text>
</step>
```

output should be ,

```
<fc:topic>
 <fc:subTask id="S0EC0A941" lbl="E.">
 <fc:para>..</fc:para>
 <fc:text>...</fc:text>
 <fc:note>..</fc:note>
 <fc:table>
  ..
  ..
  </fc:table>
  <fc:note>...</fc:note>
  <fc:table>
   ..
   ..
  </fc:table>
  <fc:table>
   ..
   ..
  </fc:table>
 <fc:note>...</fc:note>
 </fc:subTask>
</fc:topic>
```

My XSLT is like this,

```
<xsl:template match="step">
<fc:topic>
    <fc:subTask>
        <xsl:if test="@id">
            <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:attribute name="lbl"><xsl:number format="A."/></xsl:attribute>         
        <xsl:apply-templates select="para"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="note"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="table"/>               
    </fc:subTask>
</fc:topic>
```

Need to restructure the XSL based on the below condition ,

I want to apply the note template only if the note is not coming as the preceding or following sibling of table . If its following or preceding sibling of table then it should come in between the tables , below or above the table , just like in the output.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="para"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="text"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="note"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="table"/>
```

with

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="para, text, note[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::table] | following-sibling::*[1][self::table])]"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="table | note[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::table] or following-sibling::*[1][self::table]]"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin